# What SMPS topology is this?

Tags: pwm, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, buck, boost

I came across this SMPS topology that I don't recognize.  It looks sort of like a combination of a buck converter and a boost converter, but I can't quite figure it out.  I haven't been able to find any topologies that match this anywhere.  Does anyone know?

[image]

Comment: A reference to where you found this might be helpfull. C2 and C3 seem superfluous in my opinion if it is really an SMPS.

Comment: This looks almost like a "Ćuk". But Ćuk do not have C3. So this may be some variation over Ćuk converter. Where did you get this schematic?

Comment: Skipping C3 it _is_ a synchronised Ćuk. Might still be, but I'm too tired/hungry to do the differentials.

Comment: Yes, please provide context for the source of this topology.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what to call the topology, but the circuit appears to be designed to boost a very low voltage at high current to a usable level.  A diode drop from a conventional topology represents a large efficiency loss when in the realm of low voltage power sources.  You can see from the circuit that the device has a 1-volt input, so its switches have to be timed to turn off and on to direct and block the flow of current to perform a similar function as the diodes would in a topology with high voltage.  You can see that if timed properly, the output voltage will be greater than the input, but even a single diode drop in a switcher would drop your efficiency in half or more at one volt input.  The output appears to be AC; is this correct?

Answer (score -2):

I don't think this is a SMPS, as it is missing crucial components, and the topology seems off, but it might look similar to a ***[single-ended primary-inductor (SEPIC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-ended_primary-inductor_converter)*** converter.

SEPIC converters are often called buck-boost, but in reality they consist of a boost stage followed by a buck-boost stage. They will output a specific voltage over a range of input voltages (even if the input voltage varies over time). Their advantage over conventional buck-boosts are a non-inverting output and true full shutdown with very low quiescent current.

Comment: For me this looks more like a "Ćuk" converter.

Comment: Those are very similar to a SEPIC converter, but the second stage is a buck instead of buck-boost. Their output is also inverted.

Comment: @G36 is right, the last inductor makes it highly unlikely this offers a non-inverted output. The cap is off-putting, but without it it's just a synchronised Ćuk

Comment: C3 should be a diode in all cases, not sure how the cap made it in there.

Comment: This is definitely a working circuit, I found it in a consumer product exactly as I diagrammed it.